# How come $('html').animate() only works in IE and $('body').animate() is needed for Chrome/Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to use `$('html, body').animate()` to make the snippet fully cross-browser compatible, but this is inconvenient when chaining animations as they will sometimes act on both `<html>` and `<body>`.

IE8 depends on having 'html' while Chrome or Safari depend on having 'body', so therefore i must include both.

Why the discrepancy?

Comment: Which version(s) of IE does this pertain to?

Comment: @BoltClock - I'd imagine all as I doubt MS would change the fundamental way the browser is built

Comment: @Alex: They did do something with the DOM near the root level though. In IE6, `html` wasn't the root element; in IE7, `html` and one other element were at the root level.

Comment: to compensate for many things that do not work in IE,but work in all other browsers.

Comment: see updated question. basically html is for IE and body is for Chrome/Safari.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's because the scroll bars (that I presume you're animating) are built into the browser at different locations. I've had this problem before and had to use the same method you incorporate. Bit annoying, but then so are most things when you want them to work across all browsers :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing that IE attaches the scrollbar to HTML while others attach it to BODY.

Answer (score 0):

You should never even do `$('html').animate` since you should only animate content and the html tag is not a content tag. Stick with `$('body').animate` and it should work in all browsers.

Comment: The code only works in IE8 using 'html'. Using 'body', nothing happens. Specifically, the animation i'm using is `scrollTop` to scroll the page to the specified content. The use of 'body' only works in Chrome/Safari. Therefore, i have to include both so it works on all the browsers.

Comment: While, in concept, I agree that the 'html' tag should not be animated, due to browser manufacturers' decisions, web designers/developers have to be able to build script whose functionality gives the desired effect. We've had this problem with Internet Explorer since its inception.