# scrollTop not scrolling to position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to be able to scroll to a set variable, am I using the correct syntax?

```
var offset = $(".box", this).offset().top;
$(window).animate({scrollTop:offset}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can't scroll `window`</s>. You can't animate window scolling (thanks Kato). Try this:

```
var offset = $(".box", this).offset().top;
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop:offset}, 500);
```

Comment: $(window).scrollTop() [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/w43T6/). Did you mean to say you can't animate window scrolling?

Comment: @Kato: I stand corrected. Yes, I meant to say you can't animate window scrolling. Fixed. ;)

Comment: Good to know, as I've never tried the animate approach. I love the html,body solution (does that animate it twice in real browsers? would it be worth doing some browser sniffing to avoid the double call?)

Comment: I'm not sure about the intricacies of this. As I understand it, animating on "body" in IE does nothing, while animating on "html" in any other browser does nothing, so for scrolling, this is ok. For other animations, I guess it could be cumbersome. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231459/how-come-html-animate-only-works-in-ie-and-body-animate-is-needed

Answer (score 1):

The following would work for both IE and other browsers.

```
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop: offset}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

offset().top is the distance relative to the document. So if the document is allready scrolled the animation is not accurate.

$("body").animate({scrollTop:offset+$("body").scrollTop()}, 500);

Comment: Nope, jQuery offset() is relative to the document, no matter the scroll position.

Comment: In your case it's the same thing. offset + scrolltop === position. But position is offcourse cleaner :-)

Answer (score 1):

I eventually had to use position() rather than offset

```
var offset = item.position().top;
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:offset}, 500);
```

And by reading the docs it is suggested by comments it is better to use $("html, body") for cross browsers