# using $('html, body') vs $('html') || $('body') for animating page scroll

Tags: jquery

Does it make any difference, in terms of performance, to animate html AND body together (for browser compatibility) vs sniffing out the browser and just using html OR body.

I assume using html and body together would cause twice as many dom traversals.
If so, would be so minimal that it wouldn't matter?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/5231459/235710